# Visual Studio Code: shortcut for moving the cursor to empty HTML tag, value?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, editor

In Sublime Text 3 exists a key binding for moving the cursor `ctrl+alt+left(arrow key)/right(arrow key)` directly to an empty value `<input name="" />`, or an empty tag `<p></p>`. I've not been able to figure out how to do that in Visual Studio Code. Any one know how to do this or add it to the Visual Studio Code key bindings?

Scenarios:

```
<p></p>
<img src="" alt="">
<a href="" title=""></a>
<address></address>
<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<h1></h1>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a built-in way to do that, perhaps there is an extension.  You can set it up yourself with the [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by) extension, which also allows you to move forward or back to anything you can define with a regex.

In your settings.json:

```
"selectby.regexes": {

  "goToEmpty": {
    // "moveby": "<(.*?)>(?=</\\s?\\1)|\"(?=\")",
    "moveby": "<([^\\s]+).*?>(?=<\/\\s?\\1)|\"(?=\")",
  }
}
```

The regex: `<(.*?)>(?=</\\1)|\"(?=\")`

The positive lookaheads are there so that your cursor ends up where you want it.  `<(.*?)>(?=</\\1)` uses a backreference so that you only go to `><` that are matching tags.

It will work if you have end tags with a space (`</ div>`).

and in your keybindings.json:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+alt+right",            // go to next, whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "moveby.regex",
  "args": ["goToEmpty", "moveby", "next", "end", "wrap"],
  "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == html"   // if html only
},

{
  "key": "ctrl+alt+left",            // go to previous
  "command": "moveby.regex",
  "args": ["goToPreviousEmpty", "moveby", "prev", "end", "wrap"],
  "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == html"       // if html only
},
```

[image: go to empty html demo]

[the gif doesn't always show where the cursor is - but they are in the right places]

Comment: That worked quite well @Mark! Thank you! I'll need to extend it a bit because the Emmet  extension adds some attributes like `<a href=""></a>`. So that element tag would not be caught by the regex. This is great, I appreciate it very much.

Comment: Right.  This seems to work `"moveby": "<([^\\s]+).*?>(?=<\/\\s?\\1)|\"(?=\")",` for your case in the comment.  The only problem being that the regex alternative will go between the `><` first - as expected given the order of the regex alternative and so never see the "".  Of course it puts you right there and you can change the order of the alternation depending on which is more important to you.  I'll have to think if there is a way to avoid this in the regex.

Comment: If the regex is identical you don't need to create 2 entries in `selectby.regexes`, just create `"goToEmpty"` and reference this in the next and previous keyboard shortcut

Comment: `([^\\s]+)` can be shortened to `(\\S+)`

Comment: Because they are always word characters `(\\w+)` narrows it down more

Comment: @Mark thanks, this helps! @rioV8 I updated the reference to `"goToEmpty"`. That makes it a bit easier especially as I continue to refine the regex.

Current: `"<(\\w+).*?>(?=<\/\\s?\\1)|\"(?=\")"` gets me just about all the different scenarios.