# VS code shortcut for toggling the cursor between various fields HTML tags?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I was wondering if there is any shortcut for moving cursor between various fields of HTML tag? For eg., when I a + tab then line as `<a href=""></a>` with cursor positoned at empty field of `href`. Now after adding my link in `href` I want to move cursor directly into text field of the link tab instead pressing right arrow key 3-4 times to go to that position. If there any shortcut for the same?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code: shortcut for moving the cursor to empty HTML tag, value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63060773/visual-studio-code-shortcut-for-moving-the-cursor-to-empty-html-tag-value)

Comment: press the `Tab` key

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own snippet, there is an explanation in this link:

> https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets